# Change img src in responsive designs?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm about to code a responsive layout which will probably contain three different "states".

The quirky part is that much of the text, for example menu items will be images – not my idea and that's nothing i can change i'm afraid.

Since the images will differ slightly, other than size, for each state (for example in the smallest state the menu becomes floating buttons instead of a regular header), i will need to switch images instead of just scaling the same ones.

If it weren't for that i'd probably go with "adaptive-images.com".

So, i need some input on a best practice solution for this.

What i could think of:

- Loading the images as backgrounds – feels a little bit filthy.
- Insert both versions and toggle css display property – very filthy!
- Write a javascript that sets all img links – feels a bit overkill?

Anyone sitting on a good solution? :)

Comment: Sounds like a job for [CSS sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)? This way, all your "menu item images" will be contained in one image that's loaded when the page loads.

Comment: If the images are content and not UI, making sprites would be laborious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's just a few images (and they are optimized) then hiding them via CSS is no problem. If it's a lot then take a look at [Response JS](http://responsejs.com/beta/#sets) which will change the `src` on the fly for you. Try this:

```
<body data-responsejs='{ "create": [
    { "prop": "width", "breakpoints": [0, 320, 481, 641, 961, 1025, 1281] }
]}'>

<img src="small.png" data-min-width-481="medium.png" alt="example">
```

Read [this article](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) too.

**Update** - extra example:

```
<body data-responsejs='{ "create": [
    { "prop": "width", "breakpoints": [0, 320, 481, 641, 961, 1025, 1281] }
  , { "prop": "device-pixel-ratio", "breakpoints": [0, 1, 1.5, 2] }
]}'>

<img src="small.png" data-device-pixel-ratio-1.5="medium.png" alt="example">
```

Comment: Will check it out! They are a few to many to feel comfortable hiding them or doing a hardcoded javascript :)

Comment: This is great! Thanks! If it only supported alternate images for retina displays i'd be in heaven ;)

Comment: @jonas Cool =] and there actually is a way to do it by `device-pixel-ratio` (added example above) It's also possible to use custom criteria. See `Response.dpr` and `Response.addTest` in the readme ( https://github.com/ryanve/response.js ) and some more general examples on https://github.com/ryanve/response.js/wiki/how-to-create-breakpoint-sets I like to use `width` or `device-width` as prop.

Answer (score 47):

Other option. Not need scripts, only CSS.

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <img src="picture.png" class="image_full">
    <img src="picture_mobile.png"  class="image_mobile">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image_full{
   display:block;
  }

 .image_mobile{
  display:none;
 }

@media (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 320px){
  .image_full{
   display:none;
  }

  .image_mobile{
   display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't render the full image, but will still load it in a mobile device, often in limited bandwidth.

Comment: Elegant, Was stuck on this one for 1/2 an hour!

Comment: Is that seo friendly?

Answer (score 19):

Most of todays browsers [are supporting](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture) `picture` tag.
So you can use it to change images depending on viewport width.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="/img/desktop-size.png">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/img/medium-size.png">
    <img src="/img/mobile-size.png"/>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the fan of 3rd choice, because it doesn't make to load multiple images and saves bandwidth.

Because of mobile-first design, first I load small images like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <img src="myphoto1_normal.jpeg" width="24" height="24" alt="myphoto1"/>
    <img src="myphoto2_normal.jpeg" width="24" height="24" alt="myphoto2"/>
</div>
```

Then after document load I run this script:

```
function resizeImages() {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    $("#mydiv img").each(function() {
        var oldSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        if (width >= 768) {
            var newSrc = oldSrc.replace('_normal.','_bigger.');
            var newWidth = 100;  var newHeight = 100;
        } else if ( width >= 480 ) {
            var newSrc = oldSrc.replace('_normal.','_big.');
            var newWidth = 50;  var newHeight = 50;
        }
        $(this).attr('src',newSrc);
        $(this).attr('width',newWidth);
        $(this).attr('height',newHeight);
    });
}
```

If screen width is big then I change small images to bigger ones with this script. It runs fast on desktop computers. And it isn't run in smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:
use images as background of each `li` element
create a sprite with the links (images) in all sizes:

```
___ ___ ___ ___
__ __ __ __
_ _ _ _
```

Than, using @media e.g:.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
 /* here I would make my li smaller */
 /* here I would just change the li background position*/
}
```

The images 'sprite' will be already loaded in the browser and the transition will happen really smooth and fast.

Comment: Thanks, already thought of using css backgrounds (with or without sprites), but does it not feel a little bit wrong? The images are mostly UI related..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying UI related. Explain please. (I understood that the images will be navigation buttons.)

Comment: This is a pretty good idea, how do you deal with the large sprite loading though? I'm trying to speed a responsive site up at the moment.

Comment: Note that background images set using "@media screen" are not shown for print.